# Throwing a parent class exception force to throw its sub class exception event though the sub class exception is caught/handled?

Tags: java, exception

I just got an opportunity to use 3rd party API. It has a parent class exception `FooException` and it has multiple subclass exceptions.

```
FooException
     |
      --- BarException
      --- BuzException
      --- ZapException
```

There is a method name `run` from this library I have to call and this method throws `FooException` but I decided to let a caller to handle it **however** I need to catch a specific subclass exception `BarException`. If it is caught then I have to ignore it then continue with for loop. For all other subclass exceptions are thrown then let a caller must catch/handle them properly.

```
public void handleGracefully() throws FooException {      
    for(......) {
        try {
           3rdPartyAPI.run();
        } catch (BarException be) { } // silently ignore
    }
}
```

Based on my limited understanding of Java exception, `BarException` should be caught in the catch block instead of thrown by its parent exception class `FooException`. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: What happens when you try it? Trial and error is a scientific approach.

Comment: what about some `unit tests`? These should help you with finding out what's working and what's not

Comment: @Thomas Weller: yes, I could test it but it is rather a large cumbersome application deploy/test. I want to quickly verify if my understanding is correct or not before I do. For my own benefit of understanding of how java exception works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct about your understanding of this concept.

By writing this line:

```
public void handleGracefully() throws FooException {
```

you are basically saying your compiler "Whenever something tries to call this function, you must expect to catch a `FooException`". If you are catching a `BarException`, a `BarException` will be thrown, not his parent.

Consider the following code:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            handleGracefully();
        }   catch (FooException e)  {
            System.out.println("World is not that cool");
        }
    }

    public static void handleGracefully() throws FooException {
        try {
            hello();
        } catch (BarException be) {
            System.out.println("Hello world");
        }
    }

    public static void hello() throws BarException     {
        throw new BarException("NYAAH");
    }
}
```

Result:

`Hello world`

Running this `MainClass`, you'll see that you will never run into `World is not that cool`. Instead, you'll run into `Hello world` in your console log. Adding a `throw` declaration in your `BarException` handling will trigger the `main()` logging:

```
    public static void handleGracefully() throws FooException {
        try {
            hello();
        } catch (BarException be) {
            System.out.println("Hello world");
            throw new FooException("BLEEEEH");
        }
    }
```

Result:

`Hello world
World is not that cool`

---

**POST SCRIPTUM**

By all means, if something in this answer is wrong (e.g. something to do with the `static` value of the methods, or anything making my assumption false), feel free to point it out.

Comment: BarException extends FooException. It not be necessary at all to catch BarException and throw a foo exeption. Why not let the BarException as it is and catch it as FooException at the main method?

Comment: The second part of the code was to showing him that catching `BarException` would not trigger the `catch (FooException e)` part.

Comment: @Yassine Badache: Thank you for your confirmation. Your first sentence was what I was looking for.